# Rounded floating-point number comparison issue

Tags: z3

Working on an analyzer based on Z3 (this analyzer should detect overflows when doubles converted to long/ulong in .net), I came across a strange thing related to floating-point numbers.

Finally, I've created a small sample that shows the issue:

Both:

```
(assert (= ((_ fp.to_sbv 64) roundTowardZero (fp #b0 #b10000111110 #x0000000000000)) #x8000000000000000))
(check-sat)
```

and:

```
(assert (not (= ((_ fp.to_sbv 64) roundTowardZero (fp #b0 #b10000111110 #x0000000000000)) #x8000000000000000)))
(check-sat)
```

give me `sat`.

How could it happen that a rounded floating-point number may be equal to some value, and at the same time it may not be equal?

Comment: That looks like a bug in to_sbv; I hope to find some time later today to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **floating point** constant evaluates to

```
(-1)^0 * 2^(1086 - 1023) * (1 + 0) = 2^63
```

A **Signed Bit-Vector** of size `e` can hold values in the range `[-2^(e-1), 2^(e-1) - 1]`. Thus, the range of a *Signed Bit-Vector* of size `64` is `[-2^63, 2^63 - 1]`.

Because `2^63` is outside that range, the conversion of `2^63` to a **Signed Bit-Vector** of size `64` is **undefined**:

> In addition, `fp.to_ubv` and `fp.to_sbv` are unspecified for finite number inputs that are out of range (which includes all negative numbers for `fp.to_ubv`).
>
> (source: [SMT-LIB docs](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-FloatingPoint.shtml))

Since the conversion is undefined, the following expression

```
((_ fp.to_sbv 64) roundTowardZero (fp #b0 #b10000111110 #x0000000000000))
```

may have an arbitrary, unconstrained, *64-bit Bit-Vector* value.

This explains why the equality can be found to be both true and false.

Comment: Great analysis Patrick! Incidentally, both cvc4 and z3 return `sat` on both queries. However, mathsat returns `sat` on the first but `unsat` on the second. Most likely a bug in mathsat, perhaps something you want to look into and fix/report.

Comment: @alias my guess is that the specification being undefined leaves room for arbitrary choices that can affect the result of the computation. However, that might have been unintentional. Thus, I've forwarded your report to MathSAT's devs. It's good to have a track record of differences between solvers.

Comment: Indeed. Consistency amongst solvers is hard to achieve even when everything is defined, let alone when the spec says `undefined behavior.` But still a good goal to strive for. Thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you made those assertions separately of another, i.e. you asked Z3 if *P* is satisfiable, and (separately) if *¬P* is satisfiable. This is different from asking if *P ∧ ¬P* is satisfiable. As an example, assume *P* is *n = 0*, for some integer *n*. Clearly, *n* could be *1*, in which case *¬(n = 0)* is satisfied, and *n* could be *0*, in which case *n = 0* is satisfied.